# How to download a txt file

Tags: php

I have tried some things... But can't download a txt file without getting all html code. I have a `<a href='download/?cpf=1231231&nome=YanF'>Download</a>` to link do the code that will do all download code.

Here what I have so far:

```
<?php 

                ob_clean();

                if(isset($_GET['cpf'])){
                    //config
                    $namefile = $_GET['nome'].'.txt';
                    $content = $_GET['cpf'];

                    //save file
                    $file = fopen($namefile, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                    fwrite($file, $content);

                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($namefile).'"');
                    header('Expires: 0');
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Content-Length: '. filesize($file));
                    // ob_clean();
                    flush();
                    readfile($file);
                }              

                ob_clean();     
        ?>
```

EDIT --- I DID IT  !!

After trying some more I changed what I was doing.

I created a template and a blank page, in that template I do what is above and redirect my `<a>` to that page. And works... Don't know if there's other way but that's what I could do to make work like I want.

Answer (score 2):

Try :  `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`

Comment: That doesn't work to me.